# FastCGI/FPM on PHP7.0 + Apache2 on Ubuntu 16.04 server (AWS)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, fastcgi, fpm

So all the answers already available on Google, here on SO and even on DigitalOcean only discuss either about PHP5.6 or less OR Apache2 v2.3 or less OR only v.14.04 or less of Ubuntu which are all outdated solutions that won't work/give errors on **a latest PHP7.0 + Apache2 v. 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04 server setup that has wordpress with redis, memcache and varnish setup for DB+Object caching, backend speed enhancement and reverse proxy respectively**.
Just a clear picture of my setup so you don't have to keep on figuring out vague ideas or answers and get the right solutions for people with the latest/almost same setup as mine! :)

Since I use a micro AWS instance that's super slow - sever response time 1.5s to 5.4s on the minimalist pages! I found out that fastcgi is a real gold here that can speed up servers up to 20x to 50x! But I'm unable to get the right setup solutions as they're outdated and PHP after v7.0 has changed pretty much everything about folders and files where we need to store our data and configurations.
So, I followed this Stack Overflow issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/378734/how-to-configure-apache-to-run-php-as-fastcgi-on-ubuntu-12-04-via-terminal and followed the solution provided by Evan Mattson and Nazq (3rd last and last answers), replacing everything with php7.0 and removing php5.6 but as Evan mentions in his answer:

> Now create the following PHP file in the document root /var/www/html:
>
> sudo nano /var/www/html/info.php
>
> Add:
>
> `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
>
> save & exit.
>
> Now we call that file in a browser (e.g.
>   http://your-server-ip/info.php)
>
> Under Server API at the top you should see FPM/FastCGI.
>
> Success!

I don't see it! I get the usual default **Apache 2.0 Handler** in the Server API block of my info.php file which means something is wrong here.
The suggestions ask to:

> edit `/etc/apache2/conf-available/php5-fpm.conf` with
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
>     AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
>     Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
>     Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
>     FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600
>     <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
>         Require all granted
>     </Directory>
> </IfModule>
> ```
>
> And then executing:
>       `#sudo a2enconf php5-fpm`
>       `#sudo apache2 restart`

Replacing them for PHP7.0 Here's my version of these steps:

> I edited `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php7.0-fpm.conf` and
>   `/etc/apache2/conf-available/php7.0-fpm.conf` BOTH with:
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
>     AddHandler php7.0-fcgi .php
>     Action php7.0-fcgi /php7.0-fcgi
>     Alias /php7.0-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.0-fcgi
>     FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.0-fcgi -socket /var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600
>     <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
>         Require all granted
>     </Directory>
> </IfModule>
> ```
>
> So now, these 2 files look exactly (same) like this:
>
> ```
> # Redirect to local php-fpm if mod_php is not available
> <IfModule !mod_php7.c>
> <IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
>     # Enable http authorization headers
>     <IfModule setenvif_module>
>     SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
>     </IfModule>
>
>     <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)$">
>         SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
>     </FilesMatch>
>     <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
>         # Deny access to raw php sources by default
>         # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
>         # only in specific virtual host or directory
>         Require all denied
>     </FilesMatch>
>     # Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
>     <FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml|ps)$">
>         Require all denied
>     </FilesMatch>
> </IfModule>
> </IfModule>
>
> <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
>     AddHandler php7.0-fcgi .php
>     Action php7.0-fcgi /php7.0-fcgi
>     Alias /php7.0-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.0-fcgi
>     FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.0-fcgi -socket /var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600
>     <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
>         Require all granted
>     </Directory>
> </IfModule>
> ```
>
> Then I execute `#sudo a2enconf php7.0-fpm` (--> replaced) 
> and
>
> ```
> #sudo service apache2 restart
> #sudo systemctl restart apache2
> ```

And I call the file in a browser (e.g. http://your-server-ip/info.php)

> Under Server API at the top you should see FPM/FastCGI.
>   But I still see: The usual default `Apache 2.0 Handler` in the `Server API` block of my `info.php` file which means something is wrong here.

Please help! I'm stuck on this for so long!
P.S.: Please give solutions that you have found correct/working as this is for my production site, experimentation may cause something to break, suggestions are welcome but please don't go for something that is **irreversible**/**disaster**! Thanks!

Comment: What's with all the ifmodules? it seems like half the post is ifdef-ed out config. I'd strip out all the mod_fastcgi and mod_php stuff.

Comment: The fastcgi modules are there to make FastCGI module work! Isn't the question all about that?

Comment: @covener As I previously mentioned "I'm unable to get the right setup solutions as they're outdated and PHP after v7.0 has changed pretty much everything about folders and files where we need to store our data and configurations. So, I followed this Stack Overflow issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/378734/how-to-configure-apache-to-run-php-as-fastcgi-on-ubuntu-12-04-via-terminal and followed the solution provided by Evan Mattson and Nazq (3rd last and last answers), replacing everything with php7.0 and removing php5.6 " but it isn't working so all I want is someone to guide me correctly.